# Cannot completely rename Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on a Google AppsScript project with Google Spreadsheet container and have made a copy to apply some changes for a different use case.

Since running the script in the sheet requires the user's permission, a prompt is generated to acquire those permissions:

[image: Auth required notice]
[image]

The problem here is the name of the App/Script - you can see I've obfuscated part of it since it has a client's name on it. The script project, however, that's not the actual name of the contained script, as you can see here

[image]

It seems that the original script name remains, even after changing it post-copy.

I've scoured the project/scripts settings and can't seem to find where else the original name might still be saved. Anybody know how to resolve this?

Comment: How do you run the script in Google Sheets, is it through a custom menu or button?

Comment: @cnavar I'm attaching scripts to buttons (drawings)

Comment: I've tried this on my end and here's what I've observed and how I completely rename the project. 1. Make a copy 2. Rename the Apps Script Project 3. Run the script through buttons. Make sure that you've rename the Apps Script Project first before running the script. You can also submit this in Google's issue tracker: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests

Comment: @cnavar That worked! Seemed to be the rename-before-run sequencing that was responsible. If you repost this as an answer, I'll happily upvote & accept!

Comment: Glad to know that it worked! As per your suggestion, I did post it as an answer. I hope this will help other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you.

Comment: I  believe the information is stored in GCP. But default projects are apps script managed. So, I doubt you can change it directly without pointing the script to a "Custom GCP(Google cloud project) number" in settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I've tried on my end and what I've observed. Through this I've successfully rename the project.

**Steps:**

1. Make a copy.
2. Rename the Apps Script Project.
3. Run the script through buttons.

   *Note:* Make sure that you've rename the Apps Script Project first before
   running the script.

If the above didn't work, you can submit this in Google's [issue
tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests)